# How can I have Leliana disarm traps?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

In some battles, I'm getting stuck in traps while Leliana attacks the enemies. How can I ask her to prioritize disarming traps? Or do I need to switch control to her? (I'm playing a mage, so I'm unable to disarm them myself)

If it matters, I'm on PS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch control and tell her to disarm the traps. Randomizer's menu option is only available using a mod on PC.

Answer (score 2):

you can set her tactic to automatically disarm traps.

It's somewhere inside the 'Self:Any' option, I think.

Comment: Can you confirm? I think or IIRC doesn't hold too well as an answer on SE.

Comment: Answer edited already. My bad, tho.

Comment: The heck do I find it? I was browsing through the menu for a while trying to figure out where it's categorized.

Comment: The 'auto' disarm trap is only available thru a mod. However, as the answer, you need to switch and control her to manually disarm traps.

Comment: Damn. I'm on PS3.